# Java 8 Substracting Dates return 1 day

Tags: java, date, java-8

I am reading about the great new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API in Java 8

Something like this

```
public final class DaysWithBaby 
{
   private final LocalDate sheSayYes = LocalDate.of(2008,Month.APRIL,26);
   private final LocalDate today = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       final DaysWithBaby clazz = new DaysWithBaby();
       System.out.println(Period.between(clazz.sheSayYes,clazz.today).getDays());
       System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(clazz.sheSayYes,clazz.today));  
   }    
}
```

Both outputs are listed below.

```
1
2467
```

I think this result is correct

```
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(clazz.sheSayYes,clazz.today));
```

But what about this result returning `1`

```
System.out.println(Period.between(clazz.sheSayYes,clazz.today).getDays());
```

What i am doing wrong any help is hugely appreciate.

Comment: @zeroflag Except .getDays returned 1.  Not -1.

Comment: @Taemyr You are right, of course. The OP changed the code to `today = ... .plusDays(1);` and it's already the 26th there. So 27 - 26 = 1

Comment: Yes was mistyped. but my original snippet has plusDays because i think endDate is exclusive and i add one day for that

Comment: This is not the first time. I have already seen such questions about Joda-Time. Every bet that this will not be the last question and continues to be a constant source of errors or confusion. The name `getDays()` is not sufficiently clear, unfortunately. Another name like `getDaysComponent()` would have been much better to point to the partial nature of the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) represents a number of years, months and days (in that order); if you want to get just the days it is up to you to convert it.

```
private static final LocalDate sheSayYes = LocalDate.of(2008, Month.APRIL,
        26);
private static final LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Period p = Period.between(sheSayYes, today);
    System.out.printf("%d years, %d months, %d days%n", p.getYears(),
            p.getMonths(), p.getDays());
    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(sheSayYes, today));
}
```

Output is

```
6 years, 9 months, 0 days
2466
```

And 0 days is correct because it is the 26th today.

Comment: Except one thing that I don 't get.  Why did OP get 1 as result from p.GetDays.  (I would accept 0, or even -1)

Comment: @Taemyr from `2008-4-25` to `2015-1-26` there are 6 years, 9 months and 1 day.

Comment: @Narmer Yes, but where on earth did `2008-4-25` come from.  (This is moot because edit to OP makes it clear where the extra day actually comes from)

Comment: @Taemyr Oh well, I simply thought he ran the snippet yesterday. Now the OP has clarified.

Answer (score 3):

Period.getDays, returns the number of days component of the period.

Ie. java.time.Period is an amount of time measured in years, months and days.  Period.getDays returns the number of days part of this.